# SQL SELECT earliest last update of each unique product and only filled orders with quantity of 1

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, unique

I need to make a query to select the first order filled of each unique product so if I have three orders for apples 2 orders for bananas and 5 orders for oranges I need to get the first order filled for each apple, banana, and orange from the table 'Orders'

I tried multiple things but this was my best effort

```
SELECT  [orderID]
      ,[productname]
      ,[orderStatus]
      ,[customerID]
      ,[lastUpdateTime]
     FROM [Orders]
     Where lastUpdateTime > cast( getdate() as date )
      and (orderStatus = 'filled')
      and (productname =     UNIQUE)
    order by lastUpdateTime;
```

expecting to get three rows, one for each productname in order of lastupdatetime, each with all that orders information but got an error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNIQUE''

Comment: _"and (productname =     UNIQUE)"_ looks suspicious, doesn't it

Comment: How is it you know that `'filled'` has to be quoted, but can't figure out that `UNIQUE` should also be quoted? Also, how can `lastUpdateTime` be greater than the current date? How does it get updated to sometime in the future if it was the **last update time**? And if your products are apples, bananas and oranges, how can any of them be equal to UNIQUE?

Comment: *near the **keyword** 'UNIQUE'* - emphasis mine - would be a clue perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74924640/sql-query-need-help-understanding/74925685#74925685) I answered.  Please read that for the how and why, but I will adjust so you can see how it applies to your request.

```
WITH QryEachProduct AS (
SELECT
      o.OrderID,
      o.ProductName,
      o.OrderStatus,
      o.CustomerID,
      o.LastUpdateTime,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.ProductName
                            ORDER BY o.LastUpdateTime) row_num    
   FROM 
      Orders o
) 
SELECT 
      Q.*
   FROM 
      QryEachProduct Q
   WHERE 
      Q.row_num = 1
```