# MySQL query to find customers with max and min orders from each city

Tags: mysql

I have a table with fields customer_name, order_id, City. How can I get the names of customers with highest and lowest no. of orders from each city?

I grouped count of orders by city and customer and used that as a subquery to find max and min of the count, but not getting the desired result

Query used:

```
select 
    Customer_Name, City, max(no_orders), min(no_orders) 
from
    (select Customer_Name, City, count(distinct Order_ID) as no_orders 
     from superstore 
     group by City, Customer_Name) as tmp
```

Comment: What is the query, which you have used for that? Please add it to your question.

Comment: This would be a RANK query.  Some samples for you to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74924640/sql-query-need-help-understanding/74925685#74925685  I tried to explain HOW it works as well as steps through the answer.  Your difference to UNION the results would be to have one rank in order low to high and keeping first per city, then second ranking in DESCENDING order and keeping first per city.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x you can use window functions to do what you want.